# WIN32OLERuntimeError: occurs while accessing a hidden textbox using Watir Script.how to overcome it?

Tags: watir

This is the error I get when I try to access a hidden textfield in the webpage. I am navigating through the page using

irb(main):184:0> browser.text_fields[1].set "Hey man"

`WIN32OLERuntimeError: (in OLE method 'focus': )

    OLE error code:800A083E in htmlfile

      Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.
    HRESULT error code:0x80020009
      Exception occurred.
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/input_elements.rb:294:in 'method_missing'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/input_elements.rb:294:in 'set'
        from (irb):184
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in 'main>'`

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

How do you work with that text field when you manually use the browser?

You need to first trigger the event that causes the text field to be visible. Then you can input into the text field using the code you tried.

Comment: Manually I have to click on the text field and then edit into it. i tried using this : browser.text_field(:name, "message").fire_event("onchange") and then tried editing... But it doesnt work...

Comment: Can you post the HTML of your page? If you can click it, it sounds like it is visible (ie is not hidden), which contradicts the error message you see.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the trace, it happens because you are trying to update a non-editable or invisible field.
If you are using Watir "Classic" (IE only) you can write:

```
require 'watir'
 .
 .
 .
browser.text_fields[1].value = "Hey man"
```

however if you are using other browser / driver that won't work neither. In hidden/non-editable fields in browser you have to use javascript to do so:

```
 browser.execute_script("var elem = document.getElementById('your_textfield_id'); elem.value = 'Hey man';")
```

Annoying, but makes sense since it's not editable by user, then can't be "set" by using keyboard.